# Which manufacturer's logo is this?

Tags: capacitor, identification, components, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm trying to identify the manufacturer (and hopefully part number) for these capacitors.

[image: Photograph of capacitors]

[image: Close-up of logo - a circle with a small arrow in it]

My guess is they're standard aluminium electrolytics, rather than something fancy like alupoly, but I can't say for certain.

Anyone recognise the logo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> *Which manufacturer's logo is this?*

**Nichicon** (or fakes): -

[image]

[image]

Here is the actual part (UCM series marked as CM): -

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And now I'm surprised at myself for not recognising Nichicon's markings.

Comment: Looks like UCM1H331MNL1GS is the exact part number.

Answer (score 11):

They are nichicon capacitors, here is a pic of a similar capacitor

Source: [image]
https://in.element14.com/nichicon/uwd1h221mcl1gs/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitor/dp/1899629

[image]
Source: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2100217.pdf